# Resizing wubi installation

Tags: wubi, steam, resize

I've recently installed Ubuntu using Wubi on my windows 7 computer.

My goal is to instal Team Fortress 2 onto the Ubuntu part so I can play TF2 in Linux.

So far everything has gone well from installing steam to transfering the TF2 backup over so I would not have to redownload the 12GB. However, this is where the trouble arises. I cannot remember the specific amount of space that I allowed ubuntu when I installed it, but it is not enough.

How can I increase the space that Ubuntu can use so that I can instal Team Fortress 2?

Comment: This has been asked here before and closed without an answer. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226260/resize-or-migrate-wubi-install

Answer (score 0):

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk

1. You have to boot from a live CD/USB. This won't work while running Wubi.
2. Backup the `root.disk` (not required, but a good idea)
3. Mount the NTFS partition that your `root.disk` is on (this example assumes it's /dev/sda1 and the mountpoint is /media/win - adjust accordingly in the following instructions):

   sudo mkdir -p /media/win
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/win
4. Check the size of the `root.disk` (not required)

   du -h --apparent-size /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
5. Run fsck on the `root.disk`

   fsck -f /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
6. Resize - specify the desired final size (this example resizes to 10 GB)

   resize2fs /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 10G
7. Reboot back into Wubi Ubuntu

Comment: My incompetence is pretty embarrassing. How to I boot from a live CD/usb?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick  or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD